# Change DropDownList Based On Another DropDownList Value In Asp.Net Using Vb.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I try to change my dropdown list value based on another dropdown list value. first dropdown value loaded on output screen but second dropdownlist value not showed after first dropdownlist item change

```vb
Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-311HSD1;Initial Catalog=Covid;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")

Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter
Dim sdr As SqlDataReader

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            BindDistrict()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub BindDistrict()

    Try
        Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-311HSD1;Initial Catalog=Covid;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")
            Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand()
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT District FROM [dbo].[Hospital]"
                sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn
                sqlConn.Open()
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                da.Fill(dt)
                drp_dist.DataSource = dt
                drp_dist.DataValueField = "District"
                drp_dist.DataTextField = "District"
                drp_dist.DataBind()
                sqlConn.Close()
                drp_dist.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select District", "0"))
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub drp_dist_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles drp_dist.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim district As String = drp_dist.SelectedValue.ToString()
    BindHospital(district)

End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub BindHospital(ByVal district As String)

    Dim dist As String = district
    Try
        Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-311HSD1;Initial Catalog=Covid;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")

            Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand()
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Hospital] WHERE District='" + dist + "'"
                sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn
                sqlConn.Open()
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                da.Fill(dt)
                drp_hospital.DataSource = dt
                drp_hospital.DataValueField = "HospitalID"
                drp_hospital.DataTextField = "Hospital_Name"
                drp_hospital.DataBind()
                sqlConn.Close()
                drp_hospital.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select Hospital", "0"))
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Why share all the class level variables which don't do anything? but not sharing `drp_hospital` and `drp_dist`?

Comment: Don't write empty Catch blocks. You are just swallowing errors.

Comment: Don't declare connections outside the method the are used. Connections need to be disposed with Using blocks.

Comment: Don't concatenate strings to build CommandText. Always use parameters to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't mess with open or close connection on the page load.

Next, keep in mind that the sqlCommand object has

```
sql command text - no need for separate variable
sql connection - no need for separate variable
sql reader - no need for separate reader
```

sql data adaptor - do NOT use one unless you are going to update the data "think adapting = need to change data".

So, above concepts can VERY much allow you to write MUCH less code, cleaner code, and allow you to concentrate on code, and not all that reader and connection stuff.

Next up, you can (should) consider placing your connection string in the project Settings area. (it has a connection builder, and better yet it also updates web config for you without efforts on your part.

Ok, with above in mind?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        drp_dist.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT DISTINCT District FROM [dbo].[Hospital]")
        drp_dist.DataBind()
        drp_dist.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select District", "0"))
    End If

End Sub
```

it stands to reason that you going to potential have to type in sql and commands in 100's of places. Since you doing that over and over, then a really simple helper routine can help.

Next up, you load up grids, combo box or whatever in the first page load - but ONLY the first page load (is postback = false).

So, the code to cascade the two combo box can and should look like this:

And YES put the DataText, and DataValue settings for the combo box in the markup - not in code. (its self documenting).

Ok, so now we need the cascade part. Make sure first combo is autopostback=true in markup.

So, we now have:

```
Private Sub BindHospital(ByVal district As String)

    Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Hospital WHERE District = @dist",
                    New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4))

    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@dist", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = district
    sqlCmd.Connection.Open()
    drp_hospital.DataSource = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
    drp_hospital.DataBind()
    drp_hospital.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select Hospital", "0"))

End Using
```

The using block will also close the connection for you - so we don't have to do that.

And that simple helper routine?

This:

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4))
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
    End Using

    Return rstData

End Function
```

Even if you don't use the MyRst helper routine?

Get your connection string setting OUT of the code. You use that in hundreds of places, and worse at web publish time you need to change it.

Comment: The connection needs it's own variable, since it should be disposed of after use. connection, command, and reader, all are disposable. And failing to do this right can kill your DB server (no connections available)

Comment: The sql command object is a using block, and thus anything to do with the command object - including the connection object which is PART of the command object  are disposed of. You better off to do this in one object as opposed to creating two separate objects (a connection object, and a command object).  It is not as a general rule that we use some class,, and then you supposed to dispose all objects of that one class manually? Really? if for some silly reason you create a separate and new connection object, then yes, of course you have to dispose or place in the using block that object.

Comment: I guess the basic question is why is one going to all that trouble to declare and create a connection object when the command object already has one? Why?